# Cocoapods - include certain dependencies only for XCTest files

Tags: cocoapods, xctest

I have the following `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'CocoaLumberjack'
target :MyProjectTests do
   pod 'OCHamcrest'
end
```

I want to include `CocoaLumberjack` in all targets and `OCHamcrest` only in the test target.  This seems to work great when I was using GHUnit (as I had to create a specific `GHUnit` test target).

However, I thought I would try `XCTest` to see how I like it (given that `GHUnit` seems to be getting a few cobwebs and has changed ownership recently).

When I check my `Pods.xconfig`, it shows that it is including `OCHamcrest`

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/CocoaLumberjack" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/OCHamcrest"
```

So, it looks like XCTests are not a separate target.

What can I do to ensure that I'm not including testing frameworks in my release build?  Is this something I have to manually manage or can `Cocoapods` do this for me?,

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick.

```
target :MyProjectTests, :exclusive => true do
   pod 'OCHamcrest'
end
```

Source: http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#target

Comment: /Users/blahblah/:4: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting $end
target :MyProjectTests :exclusive => true do

Comment: Oops forgot the comma, try again :)

Comment: That compiled now, but I still see `OCHamcrest` in `Pods.xconfig`.  Is this what you do to ignore dependencies in your main project when using XCTests?  It seems as though XCTests is not built as a target?

Comment: Don't worry about OCHamcrest still appearing in Pods.xcconfig (that's probably a CocoaPods bug). But when you look at your list of targets, you should see Pods-<TestTargetName>-OCHamcrest, and not Pods-OCHamcrest.